# web dev environment setup

Tags: web-mode

I wish to setup a web dev environment with emacs, I search it and some post looks like a little bit old. I do not want it very professional but basic web dev is enough such as edit javascript and update output to browser, and see debug console from browser etc.

Any simple setup for basic web dev?

Comment: Have you tried anything from the old posts you mentioned?  What is not working?

Comment: Simply use [lsp](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/). I am not sure how much work it is to install and configure on vanilla emacs, but if you want to get going quickly, in an amazing configuration, then use [Spacemacs](https://www.spacemacs.org/) and simply install the javascript and lsp layers (if you prefer Emacs keybindings than [simply configure it](https://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#editing-styles)). After that you will be good to go, just [look up what is your major-mode leader key](https://develop.spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html#major-mode-leader-key).

Comment: You could also check out other starter configurations like Doom or Prelude, but I do not have much experience with those.

Comment: I try js2-mode, but it has been marked "Available Obsolete from melpa" in melpa.

Comment: So "basic web dev" here means "Javascript"?

Answer (score 2):

Install **skewer-mode** and **js2-mode**, then following below work flow:

1. Add below config into `init.el`:

```el
    (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook 'skewer-mode)
    (add-hook 'css-mode-hook 'skewer-css-mode)
    (add-hook 'html-mode-hook 'skewer-html-mode)
    (require 'simple-httpd)
    ;; set root folder for httpd server
    (setq httpd-root default-directory)
```

2. Start Emacs from one directory, say `/home/user/demo`.
3. Create `index.html` and `script.js`.
   `index.html` must include below line to communicate with Chrome: `<script src="/skewer"></script>`
4. Open Emacs with `script.js`, then run `M-x httpd-start` to start HTTP server
5. Open Chrome with URL `http://localhost:8080/index.html`, then open debug console.
6. In Emacs Javascript, press `C-c C-k` to send current buffer to Chrome browser.